# Finding grave of mother who died in Chicago in 1974?

Tags: united-states, burial-records, illinois, 1970s

***I don't know how to find my mother's grave site.***

She was:

- Born 1937
- Died 1974

Chicago IL.60653

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  I have edited your mother's name out of your question because we have to be very careful with questions that involve anyone born less than 100 years ago ***even if their relatives tell us that they are deceased***.  That policy and ways that we can work with you to answer your question are described in our [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't already done so, I suggest placing an inquiry with the local genealogy group in Chicago. I was looking for information on my grandmother who was never issued a death certificate (she died around 1905), and the local genealogy group in that particular county was quite helpful. As they are usually volunteers, it may take a little while to get back to you, but generally speaking they love to help people find their ancestors.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  If you have a link to a website with contact information for local groups in that area, feel free to edit your answer and add that in.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have direct contact information for genealogy groups in the local Chicago area. I would definitely share if I did.

Answer (score 3):

You might try searching for the record on [Cook County Genealogy](http://www.cookcountygenealogy.com). Once you register, you can search for death records that are over 20 years old. To view the actual record, however, you need to pay $17. Generally place of burial is indicated on the death certificate.

Comment: Hi, Steve, welcome to G&FH.SE.  The Illinois State Archives website has a list of the information that is found on a death certificate -- see https://www.cyberdriveillinois.com/departments/archives/databases/idphdeathindex.html -- burial place *is* included. Feel free to edit your answer any time you find more information that can improve it.